# How to secure page with angular (6) & server side

Tags: angular, security, backend

There is a really good way to secure private pages with angular? (I know there is but I can't get it)..
I searched a lot this question and all the information I was found looks the same and don't really give me a solution

**How is angular can secure pages (like admin panel) with any server side?** I'll explain what i mean..

I know that we can create a server side code which go to his own storage (db etc..) and check the credentials that angular send against his credentials.

BUT - no matter what is the answer from the server side (lets say PHP or Firebase etc..), the user can change the code in angular since it's generated into JS eventualy!

lets say my angular code is like:

```
somecode..
somecode..
somecode..
if (serverside.respone == true) {
    goto AdminPanel page;
} else {
    alert('not authorized!');
}
somecode..
somecode..
somecode..
```

When I open my devtools in chrome, after I run my app (with ng serve), I can easly look into the "main.js" source file, and easly change this code to this:

```
somecode..
somecode..
somecode..

if (1 == 1) {
    goto AdminPanel page;
} else {
    alert('not authorized!');
}

somecode..
somecode..
somecode..
```

Then what?  ofcourse this is not secure.. (I also tried it and awre i'm right)
Please help me understand what I missing!

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there's no security in the frontend. The trick is to not deliver protected data or allow unauthorized requests of any sort in the backend.

Comment: The only true way to prevent pages from being routed to server-side would be to lazy load the private module and set up security on the request to that module. That would of course involve getting the system-generated hash name for each module on each compilation. Angular is a SPA framework and since templates are rendered instead of requested, I don't think Angular really is the best choice for this kind of security. @Ingo Burk has stated the best practice in this scenario, I think.

Comment: Even if you could prevent the user from editing the frontend code (which you can't), they wouldn't have to use the frontend at all. They could just speak to your API directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular or any other client side frameworks should contains only UI Logic. 
Exposing UI logic is not a security thread.

The Server side webapi should have proper Authentication and Authorization.

JWT (JSON Web Token) are used to securely access the server side API.

As you said, user can modify the code **if (1 == 1)** , But User can See the UI.. not Data.
You should validate the credentials at server side and provide the data to the client

Answer (score 0):

The front-end is mostly responsible to show and send data to the server and the server is responsible to store and process the data.

Meaning that the server is responsible to check if the user is Authenticated (is logged) and has permissions to access that page (Authorized). As Saravana said, [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) is a good technique to guarantee that the user is Authenticated and have permission to access that data.

But that doesn't mean you shouldn't take care of security.
The front-end environment should be taken care mostly with [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks. But the good news is the Angular have a lot of things to take care of [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), but you still need to implement a feels things by your own, like [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) and [Route guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) for example.

Comment: Thanks, but I already knew all that logic. What I’m asking is - even if my server side (im better with PHP so lets say PHP) has and done all this logic and after all return “true” or “false” (about the check if the user credentials is good lets say) - the cliend can still open the “main.js” script and change the logic to: if (serverside.return == false) { goto admin area } else { blabla..}. Hope you understand me

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to block the client. In this case, he will have access to the admin page, but without data.